# How to select the latest date from 2 separate SQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

#### Original problem

I have a code which with a while loop fetches a bunch of stuff, I ran against the problem that the while loop does not order correctly.

In this case it only sorts on which thread was posted latest, what I want is that it checks whether the latest thing in the database was a thread or a post.

$handler is my database connection variable, I use PDO.

My current code:

```
<?php
    $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM thread ORDER BY postdate DESC');

    while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $rcount = $handler->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM threadpost WHERE t_id = ' . $fetch['t_id']);
        $queryTime = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM threadpost WHERE t_id =' . $fetch['t_id'] . ' ORDER BY postdate DESC');

        $fetchTime = $queryTime->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $rfetch = $rcount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if(strtotime($fetch['postdate']) < strtotime($fetchTime['postdate'])){
            $fetch['postdate'] = $fetchTime['postdate'];
            $fetch['u_id'] = $fetchTime['u_id'];
        }
?>
<tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $website_url . 'thread/' . $fetch['t_id']; ?>" style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $fetch['title']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $rfetch[0]; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
            $monthNum  = substr($fetch['postdate'], 5, 2);
            $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
            echo $fetch['title'] . '<br />';
            echo substr($fetch['postdate'], 11, 8) . ' on ' . substr($fetch['postdate'], 8, 2) . ' ' . $dateObj->format('F') . ' ' . substr($fetch['postdate'], 0, 4) . '<br />';
            echo'by ' . $fetch['u_id'];
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I hope this makes any sense, it is hard to explain.

I already searched a bit and I found that I might need to use join, but I have no idea how I should do that.

---

#### Partial solution:

```
SELECT th.*, (count(po.t_id) + count(th.t_id)) AS amount, max(po.postdate) AS lastdate FROM thread th INNER JOIN threadpost po ON th.t_id = po.t_id GROUP BY po.t_id ORDER BY lastdate DESC
```

Only now it only displays a thread if there are also posts in it.

Comment: You meant you want to get details of latest thread or latest threadpost?

Comment: Any time you do another query while iterating through the results of the first query, you are significantly hurting performance. show some sample rows from your tables and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through and can probably do this in a single SQL statement using `WHERE EXISTS` like

```
SELECT * 
FROM threadpost t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM thread WHERE t_id = t1.t_id)
ORDER BY postdate DESC;
```

(OR) probably using a simple join query like

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM threadpost t1 JOIN thread t2 ON t1.t_id = t2.t_id
ORDER BY t1.postdate DESC;
```

Comment: I do need to loop through due it being a forum, it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/yzpIc1p.png, When you make a new thread it does appear at the top, but when you make a post in a thread, the thread should also be first. If I don't loop through it doesn't  show all results, it will only show one result.